# TYPO3 page type in AJAX calls does not work as expected

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I've defined a new page type in TypoScript:

```
myAjaxPage = PAGE
myAjaxPage {
   typeNum = 9999
}
```

When I call a TYPO3 page this way all works as expected:

```
http://www.mydomain.de/?type=999
```

But when I call a subpage like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.de/subpage/?type=999
```

the page type is ignored.

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume http://www.mydomain.de/subpage/  already includes a page type... Does it work with non-speaking URL like http://www.mydomain.de/?id=123&type=999 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: seems to be a bug or quirk:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87104

it works when i add the page type in the route enhancer:

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: /
    index: ''
    map:
      /: 0
      myAjax.html: 87035
```

Then you are able to call the page with its pageType:

http://mydomain/de/myAxax.html

not very handy ...

Comment: it seems to be a question of none or all: if you use map: for mapping an single page type, then you have to map all page types in use. First use is /:0 for appending / to page type 0 - and so all other page types in use need a map entry too.